# Is this generalization of Minkowski's inequality for sums right?

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Could we write $$f^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf(|a_i+b_i|)\right)\leq
f^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf(|a_i|)\right)
+f^{-1}\left(\sum_{i=1}^nf(|b_i|)\right)$$ instead of Minkowski's inequality

$$\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i+b_i|^p\right)^{1/p}\leq
\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|a_i|^p\right)^{1/p}
+\left(\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^p\right)^{1/p}$$

for all $p\ge 1$ and all convex $f$ defined on $[0,\infty)$ such that $f(0)=0$ and there exists inverse function $f^{-1}$ (i.e. $f$ is strictly increasing)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [About generalized Minkowski inequality](https://mathoverflow.net/a/159287) on MathOverflow:

> The question that you are asking was asked in ["On Generalizations of
>   Minkowski's Inequality in the Form of a Triangle Inequality"](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-51/1/294.extract) by F.
>   Mulholland (1949). In that paper, Mulholland established a sufficient
>   condition on $f$, namely that it should satisfy $f(0)=0$, be
>   increasing on $x \ge 0$ and be *g-convex*, i.e., $\log f(e^x)$ is
>   convex on the reals.
>
> However, Mulholland's condition is not necessary, which seems to have
>   been very recently shown in [On functions that solve Mulholland
>   inequality and on compositions of such functions](http://www.atlantis-press.com/php/download_paper.php?id=8438) by M. Petrík
>   (2013)---but given the elementary nature of the question, perhaps the
>   non-necessity of the above g-convexity hypothesis of Mulholland has
>   also previously been observed.